# PreviewMacro for todonotes

Tags: auctex, preview, todonotes

I like auctex with Preview and would like my todonote `\todo`'s shown in my emacs browser. However, this will either not show at all or consist of the `\tikzpicture` building blocks, namely each line separately.

Now I realized that `\todo[inline]` for the auctex preview.
Is there a way to give each `\todo` the `[inline]` tag for preview in auctex?
I realize there is the `#{argument}{replacement}` option in Preview, however I did not manage to cook up something that will work on

```
\todo{some note}
```

as well as

```
\todo[color=green]{some green note}
```

transforming them to

```
\todo[inline]{some note}
```

and

```
\todo[color=green,inline]{some green note}
```

respectively.

Comment: This will redfine `\todo` to always apply the `inline` option: `\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldtodo}{\todo}
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\oldtodo[inline,#1]{#2}}`.  Not sure that solves your Auctex issue though.

Comment: Unfortunately not I think. Sorry, should have been clearer about the auctex part. I don't want to change my document for this. Emacs allows to set PreviewMacros i.e. in the following way:
<code>
(eval-after-load "preview"
 '(add-to-list 'preview-default-preamble > "\\PreviewEnvironment[{[]}]{tikzpicture}" t)
 )
</code>
in ~/.emacs

Would have to be something like this I am afraid.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks @karlkoeller. Already learned a lot from your edit.